# i'm getting the model item passed into the dictionary is of type error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

i am developing a blog with MVC3 Razor and i'm trying to use partialview inside my project but i getting error following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Blog.Models.BlogPost]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Blog.Models.BlogCategory]'.
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("_Menu")
```

_Menu.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Models.BlogCategory>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@item.CategoryName</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult _Menu()
{
Blog.Models.BlogDataContext dc = new Models.BlogDataContext();
    return PartialView(dc.BlogCategories.ToList());
}
```

Comment: What is `BlogCategories` maybe it is `BlogPost` ?

Comment: one thing you should change i think is model IEnumerable<Blog.Models.BlogCategory> to model IList<Blog.Models.BlogCategory> since you are using a list

Comment: @COLDTOLD thanks for your answer.i have tried your solution but the error still continue.

Comment: make sure you passsing the right model you can use template to create a strongly typed view

Comment: You don't reference BlogPost in any of the code above so your issue doesn't come from the code you posted. Search the main view used here for BlogPost or for that matter your entire project.

Comment: @gdoron both names my table name on Database.Categories inside BlogCategories , i hold only post specified category inside BlogPost